# Select and join relation with more than one result without mapping to one property

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to perform a SELECT query on a MySQL database using TypeORM. Basically I have the product entity which is related to the medic entity with a many to many relationship. If I were to execute the raw select query from the product table and left or inner join on medic table, for a product that has more than one medic, that product in the results would repeat itself with each medic separately. TypeORM groups and maps the relation to one property. I was not able to find anything about disabling this functionality for a query.

The example seems simple and a raw query would be fit for this specific case but in reality the endpoint accepts many different query parameters, more relations and properties to select and a mix of optional ORDER BY clauses so I'm curious if there is a solution to this before I rewrite the whole method, or if it's obvious and I'm not seeing it.

Raw results example:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medic_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medic_id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medic_id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

TypeORM results example:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medics": [
        {
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired result example:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medic": {
        "id": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medic": {
        "id": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "medic": {
        "id": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried `leftJoinAndMapOne` and `innerJoinAndMapOne` but it only brings the first relation.

Comment: What you're showing there are just results. If your issue is about "how to write a query", then why is there no query in the question at all?

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.